# Style width using flex in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm working in react native and I'm trying to style a component. I have a view (black border) that wraps two views (A and B). I would like something that looks like this - where I the view that wraps A has a width of about 75% and the view that wraps B has a width of about 25%.

[image: What I'd like to have]

When this component is rendered out as a list, however, what I'm getting is something like this - where the width of the A view is dependent on how much text it holds.

[image: What I'm getting]

I was able to set the width to a specific amount, but it always seems to change based on the device I test it on (different on iPhone 5, 6, 6 plus, etc.). Therefore I'm trying to use flex styling, but can't seem to get it right. Here is my code for my styling and component structure:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 80,
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 0,
    height: 180,
    borderBottomColor: '#888',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  sideDivider: {
    flex: 0.8,
    padding: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#cacaca',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  sideDividerArrow: {
    flex: 0.2,
    padding: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

...

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.row} ref={component => this._root = component}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
          <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
            <View style={styles.sideDivider}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>
                  {this.state.routeData.busNumber}
              </Text>
              <Text>{this.state.routeData.fullRoute}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sideDividerArrow}>
              <Text>></Text>
            </View>  
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The flex attribute expects an integer. We cannot use fractions for it.

I guess rendering the following will help you achieve the desired look. You can then add your interactions and clean up the inline styles

```js
<View style ={{flexDirection:'row',flex:1,borderColor:'black',borderWidth:1}}>
  <View style ={{flex:3,backgroundColor:'blue',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text>A</Text>
  </View>
  <View style ={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'yellow',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text>B</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: It is not explicitly stated anywhere that the flex number has to be integer (RN 0.61). However it works correctly with fraction numbers too. Even more in the documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-basis-grow-and-shrink) for the flexGrow and flexShrink it is written the values can be float values.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture has 3 components, but the code actually has more.
The code should work as intended if you do:
- row: flex: 1 (to make sure row is full width) + flexDirection: 'row' (so row children will be left to right).
- A container: flex: 3.
- B container: flex: 1.
At least one of the children of A or B should have a flex: 1 (or any other number) to ensure that children also stretch to fill the parent.

In your case, giving the title and the text components a flex: 1 property will probably do the trick.
Hope this helps!